# How to properly append to string array that was passed as props in functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

I have a parent component that defines a useState hook that is a string array. I then have a child component that needs to update the string array, so I pass both the string array and the useState's function to update it. However, when I try to refer to the props array, the interpreter complains (see code/comments):

ParentComponent.tsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ChildComponent } from './ChildComponent';

export function ParentComponent() {
    const [log, setLog] = useState<string[]>([]);

    return(
        <ChildComponent log={log} setLog={setLog} />
    );
};
```

ChildComponent.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

interface Props {
    log: string[],
    setLog: Function
};

export function ChildComponent(props: Props) {

    useEffect(() => {

        /* I typically use this pattern to append to an array in a useState hook:

        setArray(array => [...array, "String to append"]);

        so I try to use this with the props as well: */

        props.setLog(props.log => [...props.log, "Loaded child component."]); // Interpreter complains at arrow: ',' expected. ts(1005)
    },[]);

    return (
        <div>
            {props.log.map(logItem => <p key={logItem}>{logItem}</p>)}
        </div>
    );
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setLog: Function` is not precise enough. You need:

```
interface Props {
    log: string[],
    setLog: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Array<string>>>
};
```

And this

```
props.setLog(props.log => [...props.log, "Loaded child component."]);
```

should be

```
props.setLog(previousLog => [...previousLog, "Loaded child component."]);
```

Or, in this case, it looks like it'll always have the current value of the log in the prop-closure when this line runs, so it can be simplified to

```
props.setLog([...props.log, "Loaded child component."]);
```